# Adding or removing data from excel add ins charts

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-charts

I am working on an excel add in, and need to show data in chart. I am facing a problem to set data for chart as it is not in a range. I am showing only first 10 columns in chart.

I am using WorkSheet.charts.add() function to add a new chart, however it takes data as range only. My x-axis is very first row of the sheet, but data for Y-Axis can be any row selected by user. For example if user selected row 7, then I cannot create a range from "A1:J1, A7:J7" as per my understanding range must be connected cells. If I create a range "A1:J7", it shows data of other rows and I am unable to find a way to remove/hide that data. I can do it manually using Chart options from menu, but cannot find a way to do so in API.

Answer (score 0):

The technique for doing this is to copy the data that should be in the chart to a range on a hidden worksheet. Then pass that range to the Worksheet.charts.add() function. There is a sample add-in that shows how to do this: [Excel Add-in JavaScript Sales Tracker](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-JavaScript-SalesTracker).

Comment: well, in my opinion copying data to hidden sheet is not a good idea, as I will have to keep track of data changes and update hidden sheet whenever it changes. Also will have to keep track of rows used in charts as multiple charts can be opened at same time.

Comment: I don't know of any other way of achieving your use case. Using a different hidden sheet for each chart should keep them easy to distinguish. And just be sure to update/recopy the hidden sheet range(s) just before each call of `charts.add()` and/or `chart.setData()`.